# Handling large data received on serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am receiving data on serial port 250 packets per second where each packet is of size 23 bytes. I am using following code handling the data received on serial port.

```
    private SerialPort connectComPort = new SerialPort();
    List<byte> receivedBytes1 = new List<byte>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        connectComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(receiveData);


        //Background worker for parsing packet
        m_oWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        m_oWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_oWorker_DoWork);
        m_oWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(m_oWorker_ProgressChanged);
        m_oWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        m_oWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        m_oWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    private void buttton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        modprocessReceivedBuffer();
        m_oWorker.ReportProgress(100);
    }

    private void receiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (connectComPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            receivedBytes1.Add((byte)connectComPort.ReadByte());
    }

    private void modprocessReceivedBuffer()
    {
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            if (receivedBytes1.Count() != 0)
            {
                var tiff = receivedBytes1.GetRange(0, (int)receivedBytes1[4]).ToList<byte>();
                receivedBytes1.RemoveRange(0, (int)receivedBytes1[4]);
                modifiedProcess(tiff);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thus I am just queuing the data received on serial port in a list and I am running a process on background thread whose job is to parse packet. My question is their any better method than this to handle such large data. Currently its 250 packets/sec but this rate can be increased to 16000 packets/sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (VB converted to C#) is what I would do.  This will eliminate the issue you were going to eventually have with two threads accessing the list.  I also changed the code to read all the bytes at once.  There are comments in the code that point at areas to be addressed.

```
System.Threading.AutoResetEvent dataRcvd = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);

private void receiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    dataRcvd.Set();
}

private void modprocessReceivedBuffer()
{
    while (1 == 1) {
        dataRcvd.WaitOne();
        while (connectComPort.BytesToRead > 0) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[connectComPort.BytesToRead];
            int bytsRead = connectComPort.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (buf.Length != bytsRead) {
                Array.Resize(ref buf, bytsRead);
            }
            //what if there is more than one message in receivedBytes1
            if (receivedBytes1.Count() != 0) {
                //I think a check is needed for enoung bytes in receivedBytes1????????
                var tiff = receivedBytes1.GetRange(0, Convert.ToInt32(receivedBytes1(4))).ToList<byte>();
                receivedBytes1.RemoveRange(0, Convert.ToInt32(receivedBytes1(4)));
                modifiedProcess(tiff);
            }
        }
    }
}
```